# Save image file to HDFS using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

I have an image file

```
image = JavaSparkContext.binaryFiles("/path/to/image.jpg");
```

I would like to process then save the binary info using Spark to HDFS
Something like :

```
image.saveAsBinaryFile("hdfs://cluster:port/path/to/image.jpg")
```

Is this possible, not saying 'as simple', just possible to do this? if so how would you do this. Trying to keep a one to one if possible as in keeping the extension and type, so if I directly download using hdfs command line it would still be a viable image file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you need some data serialization plugin, for example avro(https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro).

Assume image is presented as binary(byte[]) in your program, so the images can be a `Dataset<byte[]>`.
You can save it using

```
datasetOfImages.write()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .save("hdfs://cluster:port/path/to/images.avro");
```

`images.avro` would be a folder contains multiple partitions and each partition would be an avro file saving some images.

---

Edit:

it is also possible but not recommended to save the images as separated files. You can call `foreach` on the dataset and use HDFS api to save the image.

see below for a piece of code written in Scala. You should be able to translate it into Java.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

datasetOfImages.foreachPartition { images =>
  val fs = FileSystem.get(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  images.foreach { image =>
    val out = fs.create(new Path("/path/to/this/image"))
    out.write(image);
    out.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my image is a byte[] I have added a bit to my original question, keeping the extensions and type.

Comment: This is one of the options that I was looking at, but this does require hadoop libraries. As a challenge I am trying to get just Spark to write the file. I have attempted your first method, and have had success(granted without direct download capable).

Comment: I'm not sure what did mean by 'require hadoop libraries'. Actually, dependency of spark-core implicitly imports dependency of hadoop-client. If everything goes well, you should be able to import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path} without any modification in your pom.

Comment: The sparkcontext is not serializable, so you cannot use the second approach.